# Setting different heights of Treeview Items in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am trying to use a Treeview as a menu. And i am using different treeviewItem styles.
The titles(treeviewItems) have a different style.

This Style has a height of 40. But this is never translated to the Treeview. **You cannot change the TreeviewItemHeight with a Style**

You can set the ItemHeight property of the treeview. This would work perfectly if you want **ALL** the items to have the **same** height. I want different heights, depending on the level of the TreeviewItem.

What i tried next is to create a class based on the treeviewItem and override its Applystylelookup.

This works,

```
procedure TBiggerTreeviewItem.ApplyStylelookup;
begin
  Height:=40;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TBiggerTreeviewItem.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  StyleLookup:='treeviewitemtitlestyle';
end;
```

The problem is that when you add **MULTIPLE** treeviewItems at once, the new items are positioned as if the height would be default. so multiple treeviewitems would overlap.

Then if you add another set of TreeviewItems, all the previous Items are set to the correct position, and the newly added overlap.

```
begin
 tmpT:=TBiggerTreeviewItem.Create(Treeview);
 Treeview.AddObject(tmpT);
  tmpT:=TBiggerTreeviewItem.Create(Treeview);
 Treeview.AddObject(tmpT);
end;
```

When you scroll, the items are also repositioned and displayed corretly. I asume it is a bug, would there be a work around?

**EDIT :** When you Add an Object to a Treeview, the heigt is set to the treeview.ItemHeight Property, so after adding the Item, I set The Height of the Item to 40. This could be considered a work around?

```
begin
 tmpT:=TBiggerTreeviewItem.Create(Treeview);
 Treeview.AddObject(tmpT);
 tmpT.height:=40;
 tmpT:=TBiggerTreeviewItem.Create(Treeview);
 Treeview.AddObject(tmpT);
 tmpT.height:=40;
end;
```

This seems to work, still testing!

Comment: Cannot speak about Delphi XE5, but in Delphi XE3 the `TScrollContent` (which is a container in the tree view control) cares about realigning when you call `AddObject` (internally in its `DoAddObject` method override), so there it should work. I mean, the `ApplyStyleLookup` should set the item height and subsequent call of the `AddObject` triggers realigning of the controls inside the container. So I would say you're doing it right (your original attempt), but there is probably something wrong in XE5. Maybe you can try to lock the tree view (by `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` calls).

Comment: Indeed, i did get to Scrollcontent and the DoAddObjectMethod, but couldn't really find where the Item Position is set relative to the previous children. I still use the TBiggerTreeviewItemClass as mentioned above,And when combined with the Height call after AddObject It works for my application. But it is a bit tedious and  strange that you cannot change a TreeviewItemHeight just by using a different style. BeginUpdate andEndupdate didn't do it either for me.